# TypeError: 'ItemIterator' object is not reversible

Tags: python, tweepy

I try to iterate in reverse order, but I got error "TypeError: 'ItemIterator' object is not reversible"

here is my code :

```
# Collect tweets
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
              q=search_words, 
              lang="id",
              since=date_since).items(10)

# Iterate and print tweets
for tweet in reversed(tweets):
 print( tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

any idea how to reversed the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tweets` is a generator. so to use `reversed` you need to convert generator to a list.

so `reversed(list(tweets))` can help you to reverse the tweets

```
# Collect tweets
tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
          q=search_words, 
          lang="id",
          since=date_since).items(10)

# Iterate and print tweets
for tweet in reversed(list(tweets)):
    print( tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

Comment: great, this solved my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The object that return tw.Cursor cant be reversed, maybe you can create a list with the info you need a try to reversed.

Answer (score 0):

As it shows `tweets` does not carries all the tweet received at the moment.
because it's a memory expensive operation to load all the data upfront.

[image]

As in the code base of the `tweepy` library show you are running the **Iterator** object in the for loop. therefore default method in the Iterator object == `tweets` called by for loop is `next()`.

Alternative: you can user `while` loop and call to `prev()` method at every iteration.